# Powershell empty folder with get-childitem invoked by Invoke-Command if path is in a variable

Tags: powershell

when a form is shown,
I try to get the files in a folder of a remote server passing a variable.
This gives me an empty object. But if instead of a variable I pass
a string with the path to my folder I get the correct files.

```
$form.Add_Shown({
$fold = 'c:/mypath/test';

#this returns no file
$files = Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName $server   -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -Path $fold } ;

#this code correctly returns the files present in the folder 
#$files = Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName $server   -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -#Path 'c:/mypath/test'} ;

$txt.Text="files $files";


})
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: `{Get-ChildItem -Path $fold }` -> `{Get-ChildItem -Path $using:fold }`, see [about_Remote_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables)

Comment: As the linked duplicate shows this is a very common and well documented scenario. Your local variables don't exist remotely. You have several ways to use the local variable remotely, one of which @MathiasR.Jessen pointed out is `$using:variable`